# How to get the GeoJSON of my geofence in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I tried to create a geofence in Google Maps JavaScript API, and now I want to get the geoJSON of the fence.

I tried the following:

```
polygon.getMap().data.toGeoJson((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
});

polygon.map.data.toGeoJson((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

... but it only returns empty features of a FeatureCollection.

**This is my script:**

```
"use strict";
      let fence, map;
      function initMap() {
        const zerobstacle = {lat: 9.7934792, lng: 118.7300364};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {
            lat: zerobstacle.lat,
            lng: zerobstacle.lng
          },
          mapTypeId: "terrain"
        });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.

        const fence_coords = [
          {
            lat: (zerobstacle.lat+1*0.01),
            lng: (zerobstacle.lng-10*0.01)
          },
          {
            lat: (zerobstacle.lat-6*0.01),
            lng: (zerobstacle.lng+4*0.01)
          },
          {
            lat: (zerobstacle.lat+8*0.01),
            lng: (zerobstacle.lng+6*0.01)
          },
          {
            lat: (zerobstacle.lat+1*0.01),
            lng: (zerobstacle.lng-10*0.01)
          }
        ];

        // Construct the polygon.
        fence = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: fence_coords,
          strokeColor: "##FFF71D",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#FFF71D",
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          editable: true,
        });
        fence.setMap(map);
      }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Data.toGeoJson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.toGeoJson) returns geoJson from objects that have been added to the [DataLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data).  If you want your polygon in that result, you need to add it to the DataLayer, currently you are adding it to the map.

To add a polygon to the data layer, see [the example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-polygon)

For your polygon, that would be:

```
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([fence_coords])
  });
```

To export it, use [.toGeoJson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.toGeoJson):

> **toGeoJson(callback)**
> Parameters:
> callback:  function(Object)
> Return Value:  None
> Exports the features in the collection to a GeoJSON object.

Note that `.toGeoJson` doesn't have a return value, it takes a callback.  To log the GeoJson output:

```
  map.data.toGeoJson(function(geoJson){
    console.log(geoJson);
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yfson0tL/3/)

logs:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
 "features":[
  {"type":"Feature",
   "geometry":{
     "type":"Polygon",
     "coordinates":[[
       [118.63003640000001,9.8034792],
       [118.77003640000001,9.7334792],
       [118.7900364,9.8734792],
       [118.63003640000001,9.8034792],
       [118.63003640000001,9.8034792]
     ]]},
   "properties":{}
  }
 ]
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";
let fence, map;

function initMap() {
  const zerobstacle = {
    lat: 9.7934792,
    lng: 118.7300364
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: zerobstacle.lat,
      lng: zerobstacle.lng
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain"
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.

  const fence_coords = [{
      lat: (zerobstacle.lat + 1 * 0.01),
      lng: (zerobstacle.lng - 10 * 0.01)
    },
    {
      lat: (zerobstacle.lat - 6 * 0.01),
      lng: (zerobstacle.lng + 4 * 0.01)
    },
    {
      lat: (zerobstacle.lat + 8 * 0.01),
      lng: (zerobstacle.lng + 6 * 0.01)
    },
    {
      lat: (zerobstacle.lat + 1 * 0.01),
      lng: (zerobstacle.lng - 10 * 0.01)
    }
  ];
  console.log(fence_coords);
  map.data.add({
    geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([fence_coords])
  });
  map.data.toGeoJson(function(geoJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(geoJson));
    document.getElementById('geojson').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(geoJson);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="geojson"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```